# Refactor packages in a Jar

Tags: java, refactoring, jar, decompiling

I have a requirement that i need to load two versions of a jar at once. To avoid class path collisions I'd like to rename the packages of one of the jars.  Then in source you could always easily determine the version by the package name.

I've played with `javap` but couldn't find an assembler for Java 1.6.  I've also attempted to decompile the code with [JD](http://java.decompiler.free.fr) but it never quite got it right and it wouldn't compile.

Comment: Are you looking for a decompiler or a different approach to a solution?

Comment: JD was the only compiler that seemed to still be maintained, all of the others were from the 90's and I didn't expected them to work with 1.6.  But I'm not going to be picking, I'm really just looking for a solution.

Comment: Do you need to use one or the other version of a same class? Can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: How are the two jar files to be present in the application?  Please extend your question with a detailed description of how you want this to work.

Comment: So we need to load two versions of a client api so we can talk with two different server versions.  The code for the two version sits side by side and there is no custom class loading currently. The build brings all required jars into a single directory for compilation. The app is also deployed as a WAR file.

Ideally we would update the Jars packages and then update the code for one of our clients code to use the new package.  This is not meant as a permanent solution but a true fix, (using OSGI or changing the build),  will not be done in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to consider instead of manually modifying the classes is to use some class loader magic.  I've never done this myself, but have read a bit about it.  There is an article on devx which explains how to [load multiple versions of classes](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/31614/1954).

Comment: That was considered but we decided if we wanted to start muching to classloaders we should just do it right and use OSGI. Unfortunately there isn't time to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the opensource package : JclLoader which helps in loading different versions of the same jar. This was also a need in one of our systems to do testing .

Link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcloader/